# Given the CDF for a variable X, how can I determine the probability that x is lower than a certain value?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

x is a continuous variable.

If for x CDF(5) = 0.5, then what is the probability that x < 5?

I know that the CDF tells us that the probability that x <= 5 is 0.5. What I am trying to figure out is what the previously mentioned probability is given only this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any constant measure $c$, and random variable $X$, because the probability for the union of disjoint events equals the sum of the probabilities for those events, therefore : $$\mathsf P(X\leq c)=\mathsf P(X<c)+\mathsf P(X=c)~$$ 
Now, what is $\mathsf P(X=c)$ when $X$ is a *continuous* random variable?

Comment: Unfortunately P(X = 5) is not known.

Comment: Keep in mind that $X$ is a continuous random variable, meaning that it has a pdf $f(x)$, and that you can get probabilities by integrating $f(x)$.  What integral would give you $P(X=c)$?

Comment: The PDF is not given either.

Comment: @moosefoot assume pdf to be $f(x)$. Integrate at _exactly one point_, $c$. What happens?

Comment: What is the probability of picking _c_ out of an infinite number of points?

Comment: @moosefoot $\mathsf P(X=5)$ is well known when $X$ follows *any* continuous distribution.  It comes from the definition of *continuous random variable*.